# How to keep CSS/SCSS with Vue component file

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-component

I am creating a component library where I do not want to have global CSS. Therefore, every component is scoped.

When running the production build via
`vue-cli-service build --target lib --name sc components/index.js`, everything is compiled into `sc.css` and `dist/css/1.392e001d.css`.

If possible, I want to keep the `css` and/or `scss` combined with the `vue` file or `js`.

The reason I want to do this is to enable users of the library to import a singular component from the library. The users could then use the component anywhere without having to import/include a `css` file.

If this is not possible, is there a way to accomplish the desired functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Vue CLI docs for [`css.extract`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract):

> When building as a library, you can also set this to `false` to avoid your users having to import the CSS themselves.

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: false
  }
}
```